# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_uploads'

Tags: python, flask

I'm working on making a pretty simple web app, and just finished writing a portion to hopefully allow the user to upload and post a photo on the web page. However, every time I try to run it, I get the following error in my terminal:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_uploads'

this is my code so far:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, make_response, session, send_from_directory 
from flask_uploads import UploadSet, IMAGES, configure_uploads
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from flask_wtf.file import FileField, FileRequired, FileAllowed
from wtforms import SubmitField

app = Flask(__name__)

#need a secret key in order to use csrf token that comes with the form
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "supersecretkey"
app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"] = "static/files" #folder where photos will be uploaded

photos = UploadSet("photos", IMAGES) #create instance of UploadSet class
configure_uploads(app, photos)


class UploadForm(FlaskForm):
   photo = FileField(
    validators=[
       FileAllowed(photos, "Only images can be uploaded"),
       FileRequired("File field shouldn't be empty")])
   submit = SubmitField("Upload")

#create method to get file name from file url
@app.route("/static/files/<filename>")
def get_file(filename): 
    return send_from_directory(app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"], filename)


@app.route("/upload", methods=["GET","POST"])
def upload():
    form = UploadForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit(): 
        filename = photos.save(form.photo.data) #if submitted and valid, save it
        file_url = url_for("get_file", filename=filename)
    else:
        file_url = None
    return render_template("upload.html", form=form, file_url=file_url)

@app.route("/") #define path to function
@app.route("/home")
def home(): #returns what will be displayed on homepage 
   return render_template("layout.html", content="Testing") 


@app.route("/cookie")
def index():
    count = int(request.cookies.get("visit-count", 0)) #asks for a cookie named "visit count" from the request
    count += 1
    message = "page has been visited " + str(count) + " times"

    #make a response, set cookie, return
    resp = make_response(message)
    resp.set_cookie("visit-count", str(count))
    return resp 


if __name__ == '__main__': #condition is true if script is run directly
   app.run(debug=True)
```

So far I've tried reinstalling flask and restarting my vm

Comment: Do you have it in your ```requirements.txt``` file? Have you installed the contents of your ```requirements.txt```?

Comment: It seems like you need to install this package: https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-uploads. Those classes/functions come from there.

Comment: @AlexK when i try that i get an error saying "bad interpreter: /Users/username/projectname/venv/bin/python3: no such file or directory" followed by a string of multiple "Requirement already satisfied" errors

Comment: This becomes a different question now (an installation problem). You should [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search) SO for existing solutions for this error and if still stuck, post a new question with the relevant information for that error (your OS/environment/package installation details, full error message, etc.).